# Type hints with map like function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, type-hinting

Suppose I've got a `map` like function:

```
def generate(data, per_element):
    for element in data:
        per_element(element)
```

How can I add type-hints so that if I call `generate(some_data, some_function)` where `some_data: List[SomeClass]`, I get a warning if `SomeClass` is missing a field used by `some_function`?

As an example - with the following code:

```
def some_function(x):
    print(x.value)

some_data: List[int] = [1, 2, 3]

generate(some_data, some_function)
```

I would like to get a warning that `int` does not have the attribute `value`.

Comment: your question is not so clear. but i think you can't use type hints in this case. you have to do some check in `some_function` in order to get a warning if some field is missing. please explain the question better

Answer (score 3):

Use a type variable to make `generate` generic in the type of object that `data` contains and that `per_element` expects as an argument.

```
from typing import TypeVar, List, Callable


T = TypeVar('T')


def generate(data: List[T], per_element: Callable[[T], Any]):
    for element in data:
        per_element(element)

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 3


def foo(x: Foo):
    print(x.value)


def bar(x: int):
    pass


generate([Foo(), Foo()], foo)  # OK

# Argument 2 to "generate" has incompatible type "Callable[[Foo], Any]"; expected "Callable[[int], Any]"
generate([1,2,3], foo)
```

Whatever `T` is, it has to be the *same* type for both the list and the function, to ensure that `per_element` can, in fact, be called on every value in `data`. The error produced by the second call to `generate` isn't exactly what you asked for, but it essentially catches the same problem: the list establishes what type `T` is bound to, and the function doesn't accept the correct type.

If you specifically want to require that `T` be a type whose instances have a `value` attribute, it's a bit trickier. It's similar to the use case for `Protocol`, but that only supports *methods* (or class attributes in general?), not instance attributes, as far as I know. Perhaps someone else can provide a better answer.

Comment: Thanks, yeah this is something like what I'm looking for. But yes, ideally without the ``x: Foo`` parameter type hint.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're searching for:

```py
def generate(data: List[AClass], per_element):
    for element in data:
        per_element(element)
```

So that AClass implements the method you need.

Comment: Your solution will only work assuming ``per_element`` requires ``AClass``, but it might not. I'm looking for a generic way of doing this.

Comment: PerClass could be a generic interface, so you could leverage multi class inheritance in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs the `value` attribute:

```
class SomeClass:
    value: Any  # I used any but use whatever type hint is appropriate
```

Then using `typing.Callable` in your function as well as the builtin types. [starting with python 3.7 and finally fully implemented in python 3.9](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/) you can use the builtins themselves as well as in python 3.9 you can use [parameter specifications](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/)

```
from typing import ParamSpec, TypeVar, Callable

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")

def generate(data: list[SomeClass], per_element: Callable[P, R]) -> None:
    for element in data:
        per_element(element)
```

Then in `some_function` using the class type hint and None return variable:

```
def some_function(x: SomeClass) -> None:
    print(x.value)
```

Comment: I'll look into this further in a while, but from what I can see right now - would there be a way to get rid of that ``SomeClass`` type hint in ``generate``? I think ``data: list[P]`` would be like something I'm looking for.

Ideally it would be nice if all of this could be done without the type hint inside the ``some_function``, but I guess that's a bit too difficult.